# Method that muliply elemente of a list, with ArrayList as parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

The method product() multiply elements of a ArrayList and return a integer number 'n', which is the multiplication of these elements. In class Test(), call the method product(), that operates on the ArrayList named 'lis', and print the value 'n'.

```
import MathBasic.SimpFraction;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> lis = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=1;i<=6;i++){
        lis.add(i);
    }

    int result = SimpFraction.product(lis);

    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

---

```
//mathbasic package

package MathBasic;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpFraction {
    public static  int product (ArrayList<Integer> m){
        int n = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= m.size(); i++) 
           n = n*m.get(i);
        return n;
    }
}
```

---

When the code is compiled, it generates the fallowing error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at MathBasic.SimpFraction.product(SimpFraction.java:94)
    at cubicequationTest.main(cubicequationTest.java:32)
C:\(...)\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping in correctly.

```
public class SimpFraction {
    public static  int product (ArrayList<Integer> m){
        int n = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= m.size(); i++)//this is incorrect 
           n = n*m.get(i);
        return n;
    }
}
```

The above code has you looping from `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. There are `7` total increments there when the size of your list is only `6`

Since the first index of any list is `0`, and your `int i = 0` you should change `<=` to `<`

like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)//this is correct
```

this will loop `0, 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5` and not go past the total number of indexes

Comment: It work! Thanks. I'm migrating from python to java, and I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Edilon Junior Glad I could help! Could you please mark this answer as correct if it fixed your issue? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop in the product method boundary condition is wrong. You want to reach element at index 6, however, an arraylist with size 6 has max number 5 as an index.